# convert column of date to char in R, keeping same format

Tags: r

I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data <- tibble(date = ymd("20220224"),
       number = 1234,
       decimal = 12.34,
       char = "20220224")
)
```

I want to convert the `date` column to character, and keep the exact format, ie `2022-02-24`

performing `as.character(ymd("20220224"))` works perfectly, and I get `"2022-02-24"`

but, when I apply this to the column, `data[,"date"] = as.character(data[,"date"])`, I get the char of the date counting days since Jan 1, 1970.

[image]

How can I get it so that I get the characters as desired? I want to see "2022-02-24", not "19047"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tibble` will return a `tibble` after you have subsetted it using `[`. Therefore you need to use `[[`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data[,"date"] = as.character(data[["date"]])

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  date       number decimal char    
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
1 2022-02-24   1234    12.3 20220224
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy with the command `as.character()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
data <- tibble(date = ymd("20220224"),
               number = 1234,
               decimal = 12.34,
               char = "20220224")
)

data$date <- as.character(data$date)

View(data)

data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it around `as.character()`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(date = as.character(date))

  date       number decimal char    
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
1 2022-02-24   1234    12.3 20220224
```

OR as a new column:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(char_new = as.character(date))

  date       number decimal char     char_new  
  <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>     
1 2022-02-24   1234    12.3 20220224 2022-02-24
```

data:

```
structure(list(date = structure(19047, class = "Date"), number = 1234, 
    decimal = 12.34, char = "20220224"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it within tidyverse you can do it within a mutate function.

```
data <- tibble(date = ymd("20220224"),
               number = 1234,
               decimal = 12.34,
               char = "20220224") %>% 
               mutate(date = as.character(date))
```

This will return

```
  date       number decimal char    
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   
1 2022-02-24   1234    12.3 20220224
```